# What is HTTP Adapter?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis

I don't know much about this except line bellow.

> **Browser intact with WebServer using HTTP Adapter**.

After going through numerous articles, I am still not able to understand its role & working properly.Just want to know, What role HTTP Adapter is playing in request/response messaging pattern?  Can anyone explain? Detailed explanation required?

Comment: In which context did you come across this phrase? And what are the "numerous articles" you have mentioned, can you link to any? HTTP Adapter is not a standard component of ASP.NET request pipeline. In fact looks like it is something BizTalk specific: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee267545(v=bts.10).aspx

Comment: @Andrei : I was trying to know more about "Runtime Architecture" that take me to this articale https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa562161.aspx. There I got Request/Response Messaging section which contain this HTTP Adapter but that was not fully explained there

Comment: Yep, BizTalk stuff. I think the page I linked to is as much info as you can get